# Why header(); is not sending http refferrer?

Tags: php

My streaming content is on another web server ex: stream.mysite.com. 
On stream.mysite.com, I configured IIS rewrite rules so when I try stream.mysite.com/video.mp4 it is going to a blank page and when I put a link on my site it starts downloading.
But i need it to work like this:

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['u'];
header("Location: $url");
die();

?>
```

`mysite.com/go.php?u=stream.mysite.com/video.mp4` doesn't work.

Sorry English is not my first language, I hope I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.I hope this will help you

```
<?php
   echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
   window.location.href='url';
   </SCRIPT>");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTTP_REFERER to your header, just fix that code.

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Location: $url");
die();

?>
```